# Decryption in a repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control that's bound to a table in my database. One of the data columns is encrypted, so it returns a byte array. I have a decryption function that I run in order to get the appropriate value. How can I use this function to display the proper value in the repeater control bindings?

EDIT:

For more clarification, I'd want the (possible) equivalent of this:

```
Text='<%# _encryptor.Decrypt(Container.DataItem.SSN) %>'
```

Comment: there is plenty of information over here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782103/asp-net-in-a-repeater-is-it-possible-to-call-a-public-function-from-another-clas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with the Container.DataItem myself to avoid the reflection overhead if you have a large amount of data.  It looks like you were close.

```
Text='<%# _encryptor.Decrypt( Container.DataItem("SSN") ) %>'
```

Edit:  You might need to do an explicit cast here as well

```
Text='<%# _encryptor.Decrypt( (MyObject)Container.DataItem("SSN") ) %>'
```

Comment: To be honest I had no idea what I wrote would work. I just made that up and assumed that using a function defined in my code behind would not be usable in my asp page. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, it's incredibly handy to have C# code available in the UI.  I've done stuff like that all the time.  Very often doing the same thing storing some kind of sensitive data in the DB encrypted but you want to see it in plain text on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks pretty close.  Just make sure you pull the value with `EVAL()` before you decrypt it.

```
Text='<%# _encryptor.Decrypt(Eval("SSN").ToString) %>'
```

Comment: Just remember Eval uses reflection and thus has some significant overhead.

Comment: Thanks @Justin.  It uses reflection to deal with typing -- that's true.  I like it just because it's more convenient.  The overhead usually is not terribly noticeable, and the syntax is consistent between languages and simpler in any case.  Decrypting line-by-line is going to be the overhead drain that gets noticed.

Comment: yeah agreed it's not noticeable unless the dataset is large. I'm just paranoid since I've seen it impact performance. For smaller systems it's much easier to type and read.