# How to call functions in a Class file, when inside a Repeater, without inheritance

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, repeater

I'm using a repeater to create an HTML table with values that come from a database. This part is working perfectly:
**TEST.ASPX :** `<td><%# FancyFormat(Eval("MyColumnName"))%></td>`

The function I use is defined in my code-behind:
**TEST.ASPX.VB :** `Function FancyFormat(ByVal Whatever As String) As String`
It is just a date formatting function, a very generic bit of code.

So then I decide to create a better function in a Class file, within the same project, because I want to use the function on twenty other web pages:
**HELPFUL.VB :** `Public Shared Function BeautifulFormat(ByVal Whatever As String) As String`

Blissfully ignorant I type the following:
**TEST.ASPX :** `<td><%# Helpful.BeautifulFormat(Eval("MyColumnName"))%></td>`
Sadly I get the error "*Helpful is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level*".

I have read the similar question [asp.net In a repeater is it possible to call a public function from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782103/asp-net-in-a-repeater-is-it-possible-to-call-a-public-function-from-another-clas) but those solutions talk about inheritance. It seems inappropriate to abuse inheritance for things like date formatting. Such a function is very 'global' and you'd want to use it in many different places in a project, not just on web pages. What if you needed it in a Web Service, or within GLOBAL.ASAX.VB ?

So my question is: Can you make a function available in the way I want to, without using inheritance? Or do I have to settle for `Public Class Helpful Inherits System.Web.UI.Page` and change my code-behind files to have `Inherits Helpful` in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to prepend the Project Name then?

```
<td><%# [ProjectName].Helpful.BeautifulFormat(Eval("MyColumnName"))%></td>
```

Or add a Namespace reference?

Or just put in a Module and it will be available everywhere.

Comment: Prepend the project name!!! Of course! Oh dear, this is embarrassing; I should have known that. Thank you very much. Now I wonder why that question I linked to was talking about inheritance?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Function Public and Shared

```
Public Shared Function BeautifulFormat(ByVal Whatever As String) As String

End Function
```

Comment: Oh dear. I forgot to say that I had already done that. I'm sorry! Let me edit the code in my question. My apologies.